# row echelon form for a specific issue

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have such a matrix:

```
[ 2  1 -1   8]
[-3 -1  2 -11]
[-2  1  2  -3]
```

And I have a programming task, which is explained as following:

> You have to implement a function called "to_ref". `to_ref (c, cm, r,
>   rm, m)`. This function transforms rows `r` to `rm` of matrix `m` to
>   row echelon form, given that previous rows are in ref and columns `0`
>   to `c-1` of rows `r` to `rm` are zeros. Tries to reduce rows.

If I call my function as the following; `to_ref (0, 3, 0, 2 m)` it gives me the following matrix:

```
[2 0 0  4]
[0 1 0  3]
[0 0 1 -1]
```

I don't know exactly what the question says about. If I can understand the question briefly, I can implement the code. Could you help me for a brief description?

Comment: What you need is the Gaussian elimination. Just google how it works.